# finding the maximum value of a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

sorry for very basic question but i can't find a direct answer.

I want to check a column to find the maximum value.  for now I assume there is only one maximum value, its unique.

I then want to find the index name for that row.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer @ZakS :)
but for your next question, if you cannot seem to find an answer on this site, try to search for it in a different formulation, or learn more on the topic, as in 99.99% of the time, the questions you (or any newcomer to the pandas module) have, already have an answer :) Happy coding !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `df.index[df[your_column_name].argmax()]` :)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: yeah @MaximilianPeters you're right. But if I have to be honest with myself, this question is obviously a duplicate. better to close it rather than me trying to rewrite the original answer without copy-pasting